# Effect of graphics card on game programming

Tags: graphics

I know the question can be pretty funny to some, but I have been thinking, does a gaming  graphics card like agtx and a professional graphics card like quaddro have any effect on game development during texture rendering, materials, importing assets, shader compilation, etc..

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking if the graphic card used by the developer leaves any detectable traces in the artifacts generated by the developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, the same features should be exposed to you, so it shouldn't make a difference in terms of *functionality*. It may be worth developing with a consumer (gaming) graphics card just to be more like the users who'll eventually play it, but your users will have such a variety of different cards it may not make a difference, really :) (And you'll want to test the end product on a variety of consumer cards anyway).

For a detailed description of the actual differences, the accepted answer to this SO question is informative: [Difference between Quadro and GeForce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532978/difference-between-nvidia-quadro-and-geforce-cards)

Ultimately, you don't have to work differently in any way. But you *may* have better performance in *some* of your asset creation tools (which doesn't seem to me to relate to your particular concerns -- actual rendering/importing/shader-compilation).

Answer (score 0):

The boards are simply made for different tasks it's just a question of time efficiency. Otherwise, there is no "effect" on the end product

Think of it as a calculator. 1+1 will always equal 2 whatever calculator you use but some calculator does some type of calculations faster than others.